# Overlay partial on current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog type application and on each of the posts there is an edit button.  When clicked, I would like a partial to render on top of the current page with a form pre-populated with the content of the post they would like to edit.  I have given it a try a few different ways and nothing seems to be working.

Inside the page which the partial should render on is this:

```
<div id="post_edit_full_screen">

</div>
```

_update_post.html.erb inside of the posts folder

```
<div id="post_edit_div">      
  <%= form_for(:post, url: 'posts/update') do |p| %>
    <div>
      <p>
        <%= p.text_field :title, placeholder: "Post Title" %>
        <%= p.text_field :tags, placeholder: "Tags, separated by commas" %>
      </p>
      <p> <%= p.text_area :content, placeholder: "Post Content" %> </p>
    </div>
    <div> 
      <%= p.submit "Submit Post", class: 'submit' %>
      <div id="update_post_cancel">Cancel</div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

posts.js

```
$('a.edit_post').click(function (event) {
    $('div#post_edit_full_screen').html('<%=j(render partial: "posts/update_post") %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the file from `_update_post.html.erb` to `_update_post.js.erb`

[More about Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)